# Can I transfer multiple Pokemon at once?

Tags: pokemon-go

I've been catching enough Magikarp to evolve my 2nd Gyarados over the past few days. Normally I would just catch, transfer... catch, transfer... repeat. Sometimes I don't keep up with that, and will have 30-40 Magikarp to transfer to the Professor to get the extra candy.

Is there a way to mass transfer multiple Pokemon at once? Or am I stuck with the mundane process of one at a time?

Comment: @Frank Thanks... I couldn't find anything on here prior to posting, and nothing popped up to a similar question when I was typing it like it normally would.

Comment: Yeah, the search feature has some issues with it. Tough to find duplicates sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can only transfer one Pokemon at a time.

Here's hoping Niantic will add the feature in a future patch.